# Vector notation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vectors, notation

I'm working with vectors and resolving them into their components on vector form, like this:
$$\vec{F} = F_1\hat{\imath}+F_2\hat{\jmath}.$$
I'm wondering whether we need to put vector notation over the components on the RHS, or whether we don't put vector notation on the components?

Comment: $F_1$ and $F_2$ are scalar values so no vector notation is needed.

Comment: What you wrote is perfectly fine, where $F_1=(\vec F \cdot \hat \imath)$ and $F_2=(\vec F \cdot \hat \jmath)$. When the LHS is a vector, the RHS should be a vector. However, one usually writes $F_x$ and $F_y$ (for $F_1$ and $F_2$), unless you intend to use a numerical-index notation. However, the expression you must never write is $F_1+F_2$, which is $(\vec F \cdot \hat \imath) + (\vec F \cdot \hat \jmath) $ [unless you are doing a line integral of a constant vector field along a particular two-leg path, which you are probably not going to do].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ are already vectors. (That is, they are $\vec{\imath}$ and $\vec{\jmath}$, the hat $\hat{}$ symbol just indicates they are of unit length.)

In the image above the vector $\vec{r} = 3 \hat{\imath} + 2.5 \hat{\jmath}$ is literally described in terms of a vectorial sum of *scaled basis vectors* $\hat{\imath}$ & $\hat{\jmath}$.

The expression
$$\vec{r} = 3 \hat{\imath} + 2.5 \hat{\jmath}|$$
literally means: take $\hat{\imath}$, scale it to 3 times its size; then take $\hat{\jmath}$, scale it 2.5 times its size; then add them together using vector addition, to get the vector $\vec{r}$.

[image]

Which is why 3 & 2.5 are *scalars*. They scale things. (The etymology of the word is a historically a little deeper than that, but that is the gist of it.)

So you don't put the $\vec{}$ arrow on them, they are just numbers — the vector arrow is already on $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ (although it's masquerading as a hat).

Similarly, in
$$\vec{F} = F_1 \hat{\imath} + F_2 \hat{\jmath},$$
$F_1$ & $F_2$ are just numbers (scalars).

Now, you may sometimes reuse the labels to represent component-vectors; e.g. you could say:
$$\vec{F}_1 = F_1 \hat{\imath},$$
$$\vec{F}_2 = F_2 \hat{\jmath},$$
and
$$\vec{F} = \vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2,$$
but note that now $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ have "disappeared" because they are included in $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_2$, respectively.

So $\vec{F}_1$ and $F_1$ are different. One is a vector, an arrow of a certain size (magnitude), pointing in some direction. The other is just a number telling you how much bigger (or smaller) $\vec{F}_1$ is compared to $\hat{\imath}$ (including negative values, when the direction is flipped).
$$\vec F_1 \neq F_1$$
$$\vec F_2 \neq F_2$$

Answer (score 20):

$F_1$ and $F_2$ are scalars, so should be left as you've shown them. $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ are unit vectors. The 'hat' (^) symbol indicates both their vector nature and their unit magnitude, so no additional vector indication is needed.

Comment: @ Buzz Thank you for changing my $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ symbols to $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$. It's a subtle difference!

Answer (score 3):

The $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the magnitude of the components and don't need to be vectors.  The $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ show the direction of the components.

Comment: Pedantic quibble:  $F_1$ and $F_2$ are not the magnitudes of the components.  They are the scalar values of the components.   By definition *magnitude* is positive-definite.  Misunderstood language can lead to misunderstanding, although that's not likely in this case

Comment: @Garyp I've come across $F_1$ and $F_2$ called 'scalar components' and $F_1 \hat i$ and $F_2 \hat j$ called vector components'(Synge and Griffith: *Principles of Mechanics*).

Comment: @PhilipWood I originally used the phrase "vector components" in my own answer, but then saw that this could be interpreted as "(scalar) components of the vector", so decided on "component-vectors" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks.  When I'm teaching introductory courses I try to use that language.  I also use |$\vec{F}$| when writing a vector magnitude.  Cumbersome, After I while when the point is made and the context is clear I drop the modulus symbols and the arrow.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

look at this figure

$$\vec F=\vec F_x+\vec F_y=F_x\,\vec{e}_x+F_y\,\vec{e}_y$$

where $~F_x~,F_y~$ are the  components  along the x and y axis and

$ ~\vec{e}_x~,\vec{e}_y~$ are basis  vectors; $~\vec{e}_x\cdot\vec{e}_x=1~,\vec{e}_y\cdot\vec{e}_y=1~,\vec{e}_y\cdot\vec{e}_x=0$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put vector notation on RHS until you're writing $\hat{\imath}$ or $\hat{\jmath}$ symbol. If you don't write these symbols, then you need to put the vector notation.

Answer (score 1):

Another standard notation is to put an underline to indicate vectors (when writing on paper, this is often replaced with bold face in typeset documents).

I think that notation works better for your example than the notation with the arrow over the top. On paper I would indicate unit vectors with an underline *and* a hat, so your formula would look like
$$\underline{F} = F_1 \underline{\hat{\imath}} + F_2 \underline{\hat{\jmath}}.$$

I think this is more clear because the notation is consistent;  vector quantities always have a line underneath them, and there is no exception for unit vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, there are so many different notations out there. Just use what works for you, as there is no *cannonical* form here.

Some examples are

$$\begin{array}{r|l}
\text{Notation} & \text{Expression}\\
\hline \text{Vector} & \vec{F}=F_{1}\hat{i}+F_{2}\hat{j}\\
\text{Overline} & \overline{F}=F_{1}\overline{\imath}+F_{2}\overline{\jmath}\\
\text{Underline} & \underline{F}=F_{1}\underline{\hat{\imath}}+F_{2}\underline{\hat{\jmath}}\\
\text{Boldface}^* & \boldsymbol{F}=F_{1}\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}+F_{2}\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}\\
\text{Column Vector} & \boldsymbol{F}=\begin{pmatrix}F_{1}\\
F_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{Row Vector} & \boldsymbol{F}=\begin{pmatrix}F_{1} & F_{2}\end{pmatrix}^{\top}\\
\text{Over Right Arrow} & \overrightarrow{F}=F_{1}\overrightarrow{\imath}+F_{2}\overrightarrow{\jmath} \\
\text{Basis Vectors}*&\boldsymbol{F}=F_{1}\boldsymbol{e}_{1}+F_{2}\boldsymbol{e}_{2}
\end{array}$$

- (*) The boldface notation, using `\boldsymbol{F}` is the most common on professional papers, with either unit vectors or basis vectors.
- I personally use slanted variables for scalars ($F$), bold slanted for vectors ($\boldsymbol{F}$), and upright bold for matrix values ($\mathbf{F}$). Some special matrix values such as the identity matrix, I use just upright values ($\mathrm{F}$) since they stand out more.

In all of them, the scalar components do not have any decoration or modifications. So the magnitudes $F_1$ and $F_2$ are always as is.

Also, note that for unit vectors using $\hat{i}$ or $\hat{\imath}$ is common but use what works for you, as long as you are consistent and it is obvious what your intent is. To remove the dot over the `i` and `j` use `\imath` and `\jmath`.

Comment: An interesting compilation! But is your row vector with the transpose sign still a row vector?

Comment: @PhilipWood - The vector itself isn't a row vector, just the visual style is that of a row vector. A lot of papers use this notation with the transpose for compactness.

Comment: But you labelled it 'Row Vector'! I'm not being wholly serious. Sorry.

Comment: Philip Wood's comment has some extra weight in contexts other than physics, where conventions might differ. E.g. some computer graphics texts (those that follow in the DirectX tradition) will represent vectors as row matrices and transform them by left-multiplying with a transform matrix, and under that notation column vectors would be representing linear forms. Although, as far as I can tell, the representation where vector = column vector, lin. form = row vector is far more prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dimensional space, a vector $\vec{F}$ can be represented as a linier combination of unit vectors $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ that are perpendicular each another.

$$
\vec{F}= F_x\, \hat{x}+F_y \,\hat{y}+F_z\, \hat{z}
$$

where $F_x$, $F_y$, and $F_z$ are just numbers (or scalars).